# CSS element back to default style

Tags: css

Is there a fast way in CSS to remove all of the styles applied to an element?  For example, say a tab menu of some sort:

```
<div class='outer'>
  <div id='d1'></div>
  <div id='d2'></div>
  <div id='d3'></div>
  <div id='d4'></div>
</div>
```

The CSS is applied...

`.outer { foo:blee; bar:blah; bas-bloo:snork; /*...long long list...*/ }`

Now, I want `#d3` (for example) to return to default styling, but I don't want to explicitly unset all of the parent styles:

`#d3 { remove-styles:all } /* <- [I made this up, obviously] */`

Pipe dream or possibility?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In CSS3, yes. You could use the [negation pseudo-class](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#negation):

```
.outer:not(#d3) { foo:blee; etc etc }
```

Too bad CSS3 support is a little lacking at the moment with most browsers...

With CSS level less than 3, you're screwed. Sorry.

Comment: Why not just manually override it? This class seems a bit useless. Thanks though.

Comment: In this case, yes. I thought you were talking about the general case of excluding subelements from cascading styles...

Answer (score 1):

No. Not feasibly possible. Just override it.

Comment: Sorry Meder, lower rep gets the vote :s  Gotta help out the little guy - he's so close to 500 also  :)